# How does Mozilla Thunderbird handles my key, and can it import directly from gpg keyring?

Tags: encryption, email, thunderbird, gnupg, keyrings

I managed to export my keys from gpg in an armored text format, and import them in Mozilla Thunderbird, both the public and the private key.

1. Is there a way to avoid this process, and have Mozilla Thunderbird communicate with gpg directly?
2. I noticed that, when I encrypt a message, Mozilla Thunderbird doesn't ask me the password for the private key. So I assume Mozilla Thunderbird stored it somewhere. Where does Thunderbird store my password for the private key, and is it saved in plain text? I don't want it to be stored in plain text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My questions were answered [here](https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/e2ee/T0110b6f340d1c026/how-does-mozilla-thunderbird-handles-my-key-and-can-it-import-directly-from-gpg-keyring) by Christian Riechers on the Thunderbird e3ee group.

Specifically:

1. We can tell Mozilla Thunderbird to take the private key from gpg directly by treating gpg like a smartcard. See here for details.
   The public key must be imported into Thunderbird instead
2. We can setup a Thunderbird master password. See [here](https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/e2ee/Tf541d6ad1e662879)

Comment: As of May, 2023: Thunderbird 102 has the mail.openpgp.allow_external_gnupg config option set to true by default, so no need to change it anymore.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no. There is no way to have Mozilla Thunderbird utilize your existing gpg keyring for public keys.

Per [this thread](https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/e2ee/T0110b6f340d1c026):

> Public keys have to be imported into Thunderbird OpenPGP. There is no
> way around that. This is a design choice.

This is pretty mind-blowing. Can we go back to enigmail? Now we all have to maintain two distinct databases with the same content storing my contact's trusted keys and their level of trust :(

If we meet someone in-person and are able to verify their fingerprint and identity, we have to update it in more than one place. If we forget, then it's a nightmare trying to keep it all in-sync.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to achieve what you want using the `mail.openpgp.allow_external_gnupg` setting.

- See [this post in English](https://blog.nicohood.de/use-thunderbird-78-with-system-gnupg-keyring) by NicoHood
- Or [this post in French](https://rodolphe.breard.tf/article/openpgp-dans-thunderbird-78/) by Rodolphe Bréard